# My onclick events in my php include file do not work

Tags: php

I am working on my college web design course during my easter break and have run into a problem...

I have a menu on each page that I have removed from the html pages and written into a php file and that is used with an include in each page. Everything works fine apart from the onclick events that when clicked SHOULD load another page but at the moment does not do anything.

Here is my php file...

```
    <?php
    echo "<div id='leftPnl'>";
    echo "<div class='navcon'>";
    echo "<button class='static' 
    onclick='window.location.href='"."./index.html'".">Home</button>";
    echo "<button class='accordion'>Gallery</button>";
    echo "<div class='panel'>";
    echo "<button class='static' onclick='window.location.href='"."./html/countryside.php'".">Countryside</button>";
    echo "<div id='socialmedia'>";
    echo "<img src='../images/sitewide/map.png'>";
    echo "<br>Contact us on...<br>";
    echo "<a class='fab fa-facebook-square fa-2x' 
    onclick='msg('"."Facebook"."')"."></a>";
    echo "<a class='fab fa-instagram fa-2x' onclick='msg('"."Instagram"."')"."> 
    </a>";
    echo "<a class='fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x' 
    onclick='msg('"."Twitter"."')"."></a>";
    echo "<a class='fab fa-tumblr-square fa-2x' onclick='msg('"."Tumblr"."')"."> 
    </a>";
    echo "<div id='clock'>";
    echo "<p class='date'>{{ date }}</p>";
    echo "<p class='time'>{{ time }}</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

on running the file and inspecting the element in Chrome, the `url` that the `href` uses is not formatted correctly the ./ are missing and a single quote is also missing.

Is it simply that I am getting confused with the position of my single and double quotes in the php?

Thanks.

PS, I apologise if this has already been asked - I looked and could not find the answer.

Comment: The doble single quotes is the problem. Escape quotes with \ .
And what's this? countryside.php' **"."** >. check your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it simply that I am getting confused with the position of my single and double quotes in the php?

Yes.

Look at the output of the PHP. To take one example:

> ```
> onclick='msg('Facebook')>
> ```

You start the attribute value with `'`.

Then you try to use `'` inside it.

Then you forget the `'` at the end!

---

There is no reason to nest any of this code inside PHP string literals. All that achieves it making it harder to debug.

Just write the HTML directly, outside of `<?php ... ?>` sections.

---

It wouldn't be a bad idea to get rid of the intrinsic event attributes too, and use [JavaScript to bind event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Thanks Quentin - I stripped out all the php and resaved it as html, changed the include statement and it worked. I was making it way more complicated than necessary - but hey, we all have to start somewhere right!